# Libraries vs Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm studying React and trying see what the benefits to using this library versus using straight HTML and javascript. So in the tutorial they offer up this simple example:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">

          <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentList.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentForm">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('container') 
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/znibble/mvf6vr9k/

Which creates 3 elements. All that code above, just to create what is essentially a legacy HTML!!??:

```
<div id="commentBox">   
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <input>CommentList</input>
        <form>CommentForm </form>
      </div>
```

So I'm really asking myself what is the real benefit to having/using such a library?... it's NOT like using the simplicity jQuery:

```
var div = $("<div id="commentBox"></div>");
$("#commentBox").append(h1).(input).(form)....//or something like that
```

Some might say well, as your legacy HTML code gets bigger it's harder to control via script. I find this not true, as `var el = document.getElementById()` gives you all the script control you need.

So my question is, what's the real story with libraries such as React? what benefit does it really provide?... because less code writing isn't one of them, as you can see above!

Opinions please. Good, bad or indifferent, all are welcome.

*** Note: I'm not talking about react-native (That's different) ***

Comment: What do you mean by "legacy html"? What do you think jquery ends up generating? The purpose of react isn't to be a DOM manipulation library. From their page: "We built React to solve one problem: building large applications with data that changes over time."

Comment: If you think efficient coding is about typing fewer characters, you should re-check your assumptions.

Comment: @Evan Trimboli You're missing the point. I know what it ALL creates. Basic (legacy) HTML. My point is look how much coding you have to do in React, to end up with what you can in 50 char in jQuery. That's my point.

Comment: No, I think you're missing the point. React isn't built to give you shortcuts for building DOM. That is not one of the "selling points" for using it.

Comment: @cube, to be fair and honest - there's none.
All this kind of shit floating around are buzzwords trying to teach you their own specific way of coding, instead of letting you to learn the real thing and make you their slave.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use vanilla (pure) javascript whenever possible to be honest. HOWEVER, you should choose which framework or non you should use based on what you intend to do in your current project.

I'd choose react if my project needs the following:

- large applications (with react you use small modules and reuse them, hence its easier to maintain these components and unit test them etc.)
- data binding (Simply express how your app should look at any given point in time, and React will automatically manage all UI updates when your underlying data changes.)

there are tons of features and optimizations that you gain using react for large projects or real time apps. the reason you would choose this is because in a real time app, you will have to write code that binds data to views automatically, have a good structure, etc. react offers these plus alot more out of the box for you, in a very efficient and tested methodologies and code.

the code you have is very simple, thats why you see react as an over kill in your example. and i would not use react for such a simple structure (although you might because building components is awesome!)

on a final note, there is a difference between a library and a framework, react is a framework, jquery is a library.

P.S.
I personally favor polymerJS with native shadow dom, vs react, although they are different but they serve similar purposes.